# At Least One Probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

"Cedargrove doesn’t have their own ambulance service; they use the ambulances from two neighbouring villages on opposite sides. If the probability the first ambulance is in use is 14% and the probability the second ambulance is available at any given time is 66%, find the probability that at least one ambulance will be available."

I know the answer to this is roughly 95% but I am unsure how to get there. I originally did 14% x 66%, which equaled 9.24%, which I now realize is wrong. I also tried the P(at least one) = 1 - P(none), but I got 1 - (0.86*0.34) = 70.76%

Comment: The number of possible worlds is rather small: either both are available, neither is available, or one is available and the other isn't (there are two of these cases). You can calculate each of these probabilities discretely and then add up the ones you care about.

Comment: Disclaimer: the answer isn't precisely 95%, just wanted to note that.

Answer (score 1):

The wording is (deliberately?) tricky.  The probability that both are unavailable is $.14\times .34=0.0476$, so the probability at least one is available is $0.9524$